# How to answer "What's up?"

Tags: greetings

It is often the case that other people greet me with "What's up?" and I don't know how to answer, so I usually say "hello" or "hi". It's embarrassing...

As a person whose first language is not English, I am not really sure "What's up" means. Does it mean "what are you doing", or "hello"? How should I answer "What's up"?

Thanks!

Comment: See: [What does “What's up?” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73762/what-does-whats-up-mean?rq=1) ... [What is the expected response to “What's up?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-is-the-expected-response-to-whats-up) ... [What is the meaning, usage and formality of the greeting “What's up”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/what-is-the-meaning-usage-and-formality-of-the-greeting-whats-up)

Comment: Everyone asks a question starts with "How to", I know it's Chinese. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

"What's up?" could mean any of:

- What are you up to?
- What is happening?
- How are you doing?
- Hello.
- What's wrong?
- What's the matter/problem?

You could respond by saying:

- Nothing much.
- Not much.
- What's up?
- Good. What about you?
- Just chilling. You?
- On my way here, I bumped into this jerk who was ...